# prevent Android DownloadManager from downloading for restricted apps

Tags: java, android

I'd like to prevent [DownloadManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DownloadManager) from downloading files for apps that are prohibited to access the internet by the NetworkPolicyManager. The custom ROM I use enforces this by writing an entry like this to iptables:

```
-A INPUT -i <interface> -m owner --uid-owner <UID> -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
```

The DownloadManager is started under his own UID though and therefore can download files for apps that should not be able to access the internet. If I were to restrict the DownloadManager as well, other apps - that should be able to access the internet - cannot download files through the DownloadManager as a collateral damage. My (long term) goal is to contribute to this custom ROM by closing this (security) hole.

I looked at the [source code of DownloadManager](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/java/android/app/DownloadManager.java) and do not understand where the actual download in the enqueue method starts. What code gets executed after this method? I couldn't find any clue in the other methods either.

```
public long enqueue(Request request) {
    ContentValues values = request.toContentValues(mPackageName);
    Uri downloadUri = mResolver.insert(Downloads.Impl.CONTENT_URI, values);
    long id = Long.parseLong(downloadUri.getLastPathSegment());
    return id;
}
```

In the end I want to modify the DownloadManager in a way that downloads that got enqueued by restricted apps get their status set accordingly and stop without crashing the client app (the one that tried to start the download).

```
COLUMN_STATUS = STATUS_FAILED = 1 << 4 = 16
COLUMN_REASON = ERROR_UNKNOWN = 1000 or ERROR_BLOCKED = 1010
```

But I cannot do this if I don't understand what's going on. Please help me to understand the code or hint me in the right direction.

Comment: "What code gets executed after this method?" -- nothing, directly. The actual downloading is performed by [a separate app](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/providers/DownloadProvider/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some research and with CommonsWares help I found [DownloadThread.java](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/providers/DownloadProvider/+/master/src/com/android/providers/downloads/DownloadThread.java) where the actual download is performed. As this post probably won't get any better answer I'll answer this myself now as good as I can: Checking if the requesting entity has the rights to download with help of

```
NetworkPolicyManager.getUidPolicy(int uid)
```

might do the job. But this requires android.permission.MANAGE_NETWORK_POLICY which is of protection level signature.